For a test of two proportions, how is $\delta = (Z_{\alpha/2} + Z_{1-\beta}) \cdot SE$ obtained for effect size $\delta$?
In an A/B test, we often compare two proportions $p_1$ and $p_2$:

Null Hypothesis: $H_0: p_0=p_1$
Alternative Hypothesis: $H_0: p_0\neq p_1$

Let the effect size $\delta = p1-p2$ and the standard error be $SE = \sqrt{\frac{p_1 (1 - p_1)}{n} + \frac{p_2 (1 - p_2)}{n}}$. Then let the test statistic be $Z=\frac{\delta}{SE}$.
We have that

$Z_{\alpha/2}$: This is the Z-score corresponding to the significance level $\alpha$. For a two-tailed test with $\alpha = 0.05$, $Z_{\alpha/2} = 1.96$.
$Z_{1-\beta}$: This is the Z-score corresponding to the desired power $1-\beta$.

I recently read in a book that one can decompose the $Z$ above into:
$$
\delta = (Z_{\alpha/2} + Z_{1-\beta}) \cdot SE
$$
How is this possible?

This is a rearrangement of the Z test power formula, see e.g. here (section  'Formulas for sample size calculations') and note that the SE already contains $n$ and $\sigma$.

As the link in PBulls answer says, the needed sample size ($n$) for a given power ($1 - \beta$) for a one-sample Z-test can be formulated as:
$$n = \left(\frac{\sigma \cdot (Z_{\alpha/2} + Z_{\beta})}{\delta}\right)^2,$$
where:

$n$ is the needed sample size,
$\sigma$ is the standard deviation,
$\alpha$ is the significance level (or type I error probability),
$\beta$ is the type II error probability and 1 - Power,
$\delta$ is your effect size.

Now, the formula above can be rearranged as:
$$\delta^2 = \frac{(\sigma \cdot (Z_{\alpha/2} + Z_{\beta}))^2}{n}$$
And thus, by taking the square root of both sides and noticing that $SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$:
$$\delta = SE \cdot (Z_{\alpha/2} + Z_{\beta}).$$
